# trigger function when javascript dynamically fills a form field

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange

I'm making a long form with lots of calculations done with javascript.

I'm using `onChange="myFunction();"` on certain form fields to run calculation functions when necessary. This way, the user enters in a number and when they tab/click to the next field, it triggers a function which runs a calculation and dumps the result into another field.

The problem I'm having is triggering functions based on values that are placed in fields via another function. When the user types in a number, the function triggers and everything is fine, but when a function dynamically inserts a value into a field, onChange won't trigger a function. Likewise with onFocus and onBlur as the field never receives or loses focus. Is there a way to trigger a function from a form field when another function inserts a value into that field?

Comment: Is this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events something you're looking for?

Comment: @RobinHellemans - It appears that is not supported by IE, which will likely be a large percentage of my users :(

Comment: How about this http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/ ? It's not supported by IE9 and below though you could use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for that

Comment: @RobinHellemans - Thanks for the tip! Checking that out now..